# How do you make a vertically scrolling scrollviewer inside a tabControl?

Tags: wpf, scrollview, tabcontrol

I want to make it so that my TabControl is vertically scrollable, but I can't seem to do it. The following sample acts as though there was no scrollviewer at all. I even tried putting the TabControl inside the scrollviewer, or putting it all in a grid and constraining the height of the grid, but nothing works.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tabControlTemplate">

                <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding guiItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" Height="Auto" Template="{StaticResource mainTabControlTemplateEx}">
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate> 
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding guiItems }" ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource templateSelector}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </DataTemplate>
                     </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly put the option of the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

Comment: I tried that too. All it does is make some greyed out scrollbars appear.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is not clear from the question.
You are not getting to see scrollviewer and the content inside is clipped? PLease confirm if that is the case.

If the problem is you are getting to see entire content taking up all the available space, and you would like to control that using scroll viewer, then you would need to set 'MaxHeight' property on Scroll Viewer. This would limit the height of your DataTemplate and would make verticall scroll bar visible if the inner content goes beyond the MaxHeight.

Hope that helps.